# wxMaxima: how to get decimal number results?

Tags: maxima

This should be easy but I am struggling on that.
I googled already but nothing seems to work.

(I am using wxMaxima 15.08.1 on Windows)

My example code looks like this:

```
kill (all);
numer:true;

sigma_z: 1000.0$ /*[N/mm²]*/
sigma_b_zul : simga_z*0.7;
sigma_b_zul : simga_z*0.7, numer;
sigma_b_zul : simga_z*0.7, numer:true;
float(sigma_b_zul);
```

the output is every time:

```
0.7 simga_z
```

the next cell looks like:

```
d_d: 1000$ /*dfd*/
sigma_g_f_d: d_d * 0.7;
```

the result is:

```
7.0E+2
```

I am completely clueless why maxima behaves like this. Can anyone help?

Comment: I think you have a typo: `sigma_z` and `simga_z`.

Comment: @slitvinov : you should change your comment to the answer

Answer (score 0):

The variable you define is

```
sigma_z: 1000.0$ /*[N/mm²]*/
```

but then you call

```
simga_z*0.7;
```

Please, notice the difference between si**gm**a_z and si**mg**a_z.